# how to change volume on the left/right side of a audio JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

how to make `onclick` the sound start only on a side of the earphones

like for example right or left.

> something like this: https://www.onlinemictest.com/sound-test/

so if it plays the sound on the left it, the right earphone doesn't need to make any sound.

---

I think it can be done by using volumes or something like that. how to do that?

(I can't edit the sound in a video editor, I want it will automatically done by javascript)

```js
function playSound(options) {
  const choosedDirection = () => {
    return Object.keys(options)
      .reverse()
      .find(
        (direction) => direction === "left" || direction === "right",
      );
  };

  const audio = new Audio("audio.mp3");

  switch (choosedDirection()) {
    case "left":
      audio.play();
      // how to make here play only on the left side
      // by making the volume high on the left and 0 on the right
      break;
    case "right":
      audio.play();
      // how to make here play only on the right side
      // by making the volume high on the right and 0 on the left
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/"></script>
</head>

<body class="h-screen grid place-items-center bg-gray-200 overflow-hidden">
  <div class="flex gap-[5vmin]">
    <div class="flex gap-[5vmin]">
    <!-- left -->
      <button title=" Left sound" class="transition hover:-translate-y-1 hover:shadow-2xl focus:rotate-3 hover:border-blue-200 hover:shadow-blue-200 focus:border-blue-500 focus:shadow-blue-500 border-4 border-blue-50 shadow-md p-[10vmin] bg-white rounded-[3vmin] text-[10vmin] text-blue-500 after:content-[attr(title)] relative after:absolute after:text-sm after:-bottom-20 after:left-0 after:w-max after:bg-white after:shadow-lg after:-translate-x-[50%] after:left-[50%] after:px-4 after:py-2 after:rounded-lg after:opacity-0 focus:after:opacity-100 focus:after:duration-500 after:translate-y-12 focus:after:translate-y-0 focus:after:animate-pulse focus:animate-bounce"
        onclick="playSound({left:true})">
        
      </button>
      
      <!-- right -->
      <button title=" Right sound" class="transition hover:-translate-y-1 hover:shadow-2xl focus:rotate-3 hover:border-blue-200 hover:shadow-blue-200 focus:border-blue-500 focus:shadow-blue-500 border-4 border-blue-50 shadow-md p-[10vmin] bg-white rounded-[3vmin] text-[10vmin] text-blue-500 after:content-[attr(title)] relative after:absolute after:text-sm after:-bottom-20 after:left-0 after:w-max after:bg-white after:shadow-lg after:-translate-x-[50%] after:left-[50%] after:px-4 after:py-2 after:rounded-lg after:opacity-0 focus:after:opacity-100 focus:after:duration-500 after:translate-y-12 focus:after:translate-y-0 focus:after:animate-pulse focus:animate-bounce"
        onclick="playSound({right:true})">
        
      </button>
    </div>

    <script>
      console.clear(); // not important, just to delete the tailwind warning of using CDN instead of NPM package
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You may want to use an AudioContext PannerNode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createStereoPanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```js
const audioUrl = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3";
const audioElement = new Audio(audioUrl);
audioElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

const audioContext = new AudioContext();

const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

const volumeNodeL = new GainNode(audioContext);
const volumeNodeR = new GainNode(audioContext);

volumeNodeL.gain.value = 2;
volumeNodeR.gain.value = 2;

const channelsCount = 2;

const splitterNode = new ChannelSplitterNode(audioContext, {
  numberOfOutputs: channelsCount
});
const mergerNode = new ChannelMergerNode(audioContext, {
  numberOfInputs: channelsCount
});

audioSource.connect(splitterNode);

splitterNode.connect(volumeNodeL, 0);
splitterNode.connect(volumeNodeR, 1);

volumeNodeL.connect(mergerNode, 0, 0);
volumeNodeR.connect(mergerNode, 0, 1);

mergerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

let isPlaying;

function playPause() {
  if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
    audioContext.resume();
  }

  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  if (isPlaying) {
    audioElement.play();
  } else {
    audioElement.pause();
  }
}

function setBalance(val) {
  volumeNodeL.gain.value = 1 - val;
  volumeNodeR.gain.value = 1 + val;
}
```

```html
<h3>Check if your speakers are connected and working with this test.</h3>

<button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="setBalance(-1)"> Left</button>
<button onclick="setBalance(0)"> Center</button>
<button onclick="setBalance(+1)"> Right</button>
```

Comment: is really working bro, really fantastic bro.

Comment: if you can, can you add a little explain (especially in this `GainNode`, `splitterNode`, `mergerNode`) and how javascript know is right and left if GainNode is the same name code. sorry for my questions (if you add a simple explain the code I will add you a bounty if stackoverflow allow it). technically the code works but I don't know why (I think also link to me docs is fine if you can't explain it). thanks for your work!

Comment: i tried to see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode?retiredLocale=it but still don't understand, can you add a simple explanation if you can? it will be very helpful :)

Comment: if in the future you will see this comment, please help me by adding a simple explanation to that code (I will add you a bounty so you can know that you really help me, but pls do that and thanks a lot)